# How to stop a running process when launching a new one automatically?

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea

It happens often that I would like to just run a new debug instance without having to manually end the previous running one, since you can only have one Air instance running at the same time with the same app id.

Anyone knows how to kill the previous running instance and launch a new one automatically everytime you debug it?.

Comment: run another instance of idea? they use pipes to access debug air instance, so you either end debug session (this closes the air player) or not, then you can't start another one.

Comment: Why would I run 2 IDEA instances? that's even more cumbersome. Flash Builder for example does this, if you have a running one the moment you click run again, it kills it and run a new one.